# Errors while uploading Laravel project to fortrabbit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fortrabbit

So I tried to install a fresh laravel to fortrabbit. But when i go to the site it only say "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I followed the fortrabbit instruction:

```
# 1. Use Composer to create a local Laravel project named like your App
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist phalcon-tzgl
# this installs Laravel locally and will take a while

# 2. Change into the folder
cd phalcon-tzgl

# 3. Initialize a local Git repo
git init .

# 4. Add all files
git add -A

# 5. Commit files for the first time
git commit -m 'Initial'

# 6. Add fortrabbit as a remote
git remote add fortrabbit phalcon-tzgl.fuzg50672x0fi6xv@deploy.eu2.frbit.com:phalcon-tzgl.git

# 7. Push changes to fortrabbit
git push -u fortrabbit master
# this will install Laravel on remote and take another while
# the next deployments will be much faster
```

Then I change the .env file:

```
APP_KEY=UlQ9WLW9UOELwhzKqtFStpbHKNKGdl82
APP_ENV=production
DB_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
DB_HOST=${MYSQL_HOST}
DB_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
DB_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
DB_PORT=${MYSQL_PORT}
DB_USERNAME=${MYSQL_USER}
```

And I change the root to "/public".

It didnt work!
Then I

```
git clone phalcon-tzgl.*************@deploy.eu2.frbit.com:phalcon-tzgl.git
```

And I try from my local server and I got this

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\phalcon-tzgl\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phalcon-tzgl\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\phalcon-tzgl\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\phalcon-tzgl\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

I dont know what I did wrong,please help!

Answer (score 0):

run `composer install` to actually install all your packages and create the autoload file you're missing.